# `%d` and `%y` in formating string

Tags: bash

I came across symbol `%y` and `%d` during following a tutorial.

`for i in $(stat -c %y "$1"/* | cut -c 12-13); do`
`printf "\nTotal files = %d\n" $count`

Checked that there's no options or primaries named "%y"

```
    $ man stat | egrep -o "%y"
    return nothing
```

I see that `%d` is for digit in other language, but cannot find it from [Bash Reference Manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html).

What does they mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `printf` may be a bash built-in, `stat` is not. It therefore depends entirely on what variant/version of `stat` you have installed.

When *I* run your `man/grep` combo, I actually get output since my `stat` is GNU's version 8.2.

I suggest you run `stat --version` to see which version you actually *have,* and then `stat -c %y /` to see if that format specifier works for your version. It may well be that your `man` page is out of data.

If it turns out your `stat` does *not* support the format specifiers you need, you can always download, compile and use GNU's version to get around the problem.

---

In terms of why you can't find `%d` in that `bash` link, it's because it has this little beauty in it (which you should also see if you run `man bash-builtins` and search for `printf`):

> In addition to the standard `printf(1)` formats, `printf` interprets the following extensions ...

In other words, it only lists the *extensions* to the standard format specifiers. If you run `man 1 printf`, you'll see it supports:

> ... all C format specifications ending with one of `diouxXfeEgGcs`.

Answer (score 1):

```
     %y   time of last data modification, human-readable

stat --version
stat (GNU coreutils) 8.28
Copyright © 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```